# Symfony - manyToMany not getting saved

Tags: php, symfony

**The Scenario**

I have two Entities linked together with `manyToMany` relation.

Entities

1. `User`
2. `Interest`

So on a user's profile form there is a field called `Interests` which is rendered using [select2](https://select2.github.io/).

Now a user can select as many Interests as they want and upon saving doctrine is doing the nice job of saving the selected Interests in the linked table. When I reload the profile page I can see that interests that I already selected.

[image]

**The Problem**

Although the form field is linked with an `Interest` entity

```
            $form->add('interest', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Interest',
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false)
```

A user can also add interests of their own which do not exist in `Interest` table with the help of [Tagging Support](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags) on front end and on backend to save this information I have [Form Event Subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-subscriber-to-a-form-class) in place that checks if any of the Interests submitted by the user does not exist in `Interest` table add them and it is here where I get the following exception

```
    Message
           This value is not valid. 

    Origin
           interest 

   Cause
            Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
            Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[interest] = [0 => 1, 1 => 4, 2 => 7, 3 => www]


    Caused by:
            Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException
            Unable to reverse value for property path "interest": Could not find all matching choices for the given values


    Caused by:
            Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException
            Could not find all matching choices for the given values
```

Here is the Event Subscriber code

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\EventListener;


use AppBundle\Entity\Interest;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;


class AddProfileFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $authorizationChecker;

    protected $em;

    function __construct(AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // Tells the dispatcher that you want to listen on the form.pre_set_data
        // event and that the preSetData method should be called.
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'onPreSubmit'
            );
    }


    /**
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event){

        $interestTags = $event->getData();
        $interestTags = $interestTags['interest'];
        foreach($interestTags as $interestTag){
            $interest = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Interest')->findOneBy(array('id' => $interestTag));
            if(!$interest){
                $newInterest = new Interest();
                $newInterest->setName($interestTag);
                $this->em->persist($newInterest);
                $this->em->flush();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**The Attempt**

I updated the form code to as following by adding `choice_value`

```
        $form->add('interest', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Interest',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'choice_value' => 'name'
            )
        );
```

and I changed the query inside the Event Subscriber from

```
$interest = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Interest')->findOneBy(array('id' => $interestTag));
```

to

```
$interest = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Interest')->findOneBy(array('name' => $interestTag));
```

This worked perfectly at first but when I reload the profile page my interest field appears empty

[image]

The reason why it appears empty is because (my assumption) of `id="select2-user_interest-result-5z18-Education"` I think that needs to look something like `id="select2-user_interest-result-5z18-66"`

```
<ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" aria-multiselectable="true" id="select2-user_interest-results"
aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-user_interest-result-5z18-Education" role="treeitem"
    aria-selected="false">Education
</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-user_interest-result-rdka-History" role="treeitem"
    aria-selected="false">History
</li>
<li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted"
    id="select2-user_interest-result-lfq4-Architecture" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Architecture
</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-user_interest-result-qqiq-Entrepreneurship" role="treeitem"
    aria-selected="false">Entrepreneurship
</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-user_interest-result-qutx-Technology" role="treeitem"
    aria-selected="false">Technology
</li>
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-user_interest-result-sfx4-Engineering" role="treeitem"
    aria-selected="false">Engineering
</li>
```

I crossed check the data in Interest table and I can see the new interests added by the user which did not exist before, so its working but on front end its not being displayed. Out of curiosity i removed the `choice_value` and then reloaded the profile page and I could see the new interests

[image]

I will really appreciate if anything can push me in right direction and let me know what am I missing and how can i get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that as `EntityType` extend `ChoiceType` which doesn't allow adding new values in the choice list.

You should use `CollectionType` like in the cookbook http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

To make a proper select in your code, you'll also have to insert in the view, along with your form, the full list of all interests.

Then your view should looks like :

```
<select name='{{ form.interest.vars.full_name }}' id="{{ form.interest.vars.id }}" class='select2'>
    {% for interestList as interestItem %}
        <option value='{{ interestItem.id }}' {% if some_logic_to_check_whether_the_item_is_selected  %}selected='selected'{% endif %} >{{ interestItem.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: I am actually able to add using the approach i mentioned under `The Attempt` but the drawback of that is the select2 field appears empty however in database i can see the new data being added and linked to the user